# How to make vertical line not show up in legend?

Tags: matlab

I have the following Matlab script:

```
%%// Create a function handle of your function
f = @(x,a) 976.975786299./x + 1.67417230901e-4*x./a;
%%// Plot the data
x = linspace(500, 15000);
as = 7:10;
plot(x, bsxfun(f,x(:),as));
%%// Add a legend
legendTexts = arrayfun(@(a) sprintf('A = %d', a), as, 'uni', 0);
legend(legendTexts, 'Location', 'best');
xlabel(gca, '$W_{to}/S_w$ (Pa)', ...
        'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
        'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
        'FontSize', 14, ...
        'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
        'FontAngle', 'normal')
ylabel(gca, {'$T_{to}/W_{to}$'}, ...
        'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
        'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
        'FontSize', 14, ...
        'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
        'FontAngle', 'normal')
hold 'on'

f = @(x,a) functions(x,a)
%%// Plot the data
x = linspace(1, 15000,30000);
y = bsxfun(f,x(:),1.9)
as = 1.9:0.1:2.4;
plot(x, bsxfun(f,x(:),as));
%%// Add a legend
legendTexts = arrayfun(@(a) sprintf('C_{L{max}_{TO}} = %g', a), as, 'uni', 0);
legend(legendTexts, 'Location', 'best');
xlabel(gca, '$W_{to}/S_w$ (Pa)', ...
        'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
        'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
        'FontSize', 14, ...
        'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
        'FontAngle', 'normal')
ylabel(gca, {'$T_{to}/W_{to}$'}, ...
        'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
        'FontName', 'Times New Roman', ...
        'FontSize', 14, ...
        'FontWeight', 'normal', ...
        'FontAngle', 'normal')
    xline(5717,'k','LineWidth',1)
    function y = functions(x,a)
    Bounds_1 = [0,((2.34117647059/(18.0173492479 - 3.14916666667*a)) + 5.61882352942e-2)/(1.53640039877e-4/a)];
    Bounds_2 = [((2.34117647059/(18.0173492479 - 3.14916666667*a)) + 5.61882352942e-2)/(1.53640039877e-4/a),15000];
    Bounds = [Bounds_1 Bounds_2];
    Min = min(Bounds);
    Max = max(Bounds);
    f1 = ((2.34117647059./(18.0173492479 - 3.14916666667*a)) + 5.61882352942e-2).*(Bounds_1(1) < x & x < Bounds_1(2));
    f2 = (1.53640039877e-4*x/a).*(Bounds_2(1) < x & x <= Bounds_2(2));
    y = f1 + f2;
    end
```

The legend shows "data1" on the horizontal line. How do I remove that? I've tried different ways of attempting to remove it, but I can't seem to find the way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `HandleVisibility` property on lines to "hide" them from things like the legend

```
xline(5717,'k','LineWidth',1,'HandleVisibility','off');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your vertical line to a variable (`x` below) and then remove the DisplayName so it doesn't appear in the legend.  Finally, place the legend call below that.

```
x=xline(5717,'k','LineWidth',1);
x.DisplayName = '';
legend(legendTexts, 'Location', 'best');`
```

It looks fine on my side after making these changes.